# Creating a new hypothesis based on data from my old hypothesis?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, p-value

Suppose I have a set of null and alternative hypothesis $(G_0,G_1)$ where I reject $G_0$ at the $5\%$ significance level. I then use my collected data to develop a new set of hypotheses $(H_0,H_1)$. Let's say now my $p$-value in this case is $1\%$.

Blindly follow the usual approach tells me that I cannot reject $H_0$ at the $5\%$ or $1\%$ significance levels. But am I allowed to do this? The arguments I have for and against is:

1. The approach is wrong. Remembering that the $p$-value is the conditional probability of observing the collected data given that the null hypothesis $H_0$ is true, I am using an incorrect set of priors for the second set of hypotheses.
2. There is nothing wrong with this approach, the two are simply completely different experiment and the usual approach is fine.

I am not a statistician, so this question might be a little too vaguely phrased, please inform me if any clarification is needed. Filtering out the inexcusable is difficult for me!

Comment: There is debate about this, but generally speaking, the scientific method stipulates that you form your hypothesis before you collect the data to test that hypothesis. Once you've gotten some data and tested your hypothesis, it is a commonplace to form a new hypothesis, then get some new data, and test that. Certainly nothing wrong with that. I don't know if this answers your question, though.

Comment: @AdrianKeister that's great, I certainly see how the second argument is essentially the scientific method; but is argument 1 phrased correctly? What would you say are the pros and cons/particular counterarguments to each statement?

Comment: I can't say, because you haven't really spelled out the exact order of events. The scientific method says the order is this: 1. Formulate hypothesis. 2. Design experiment to test hypothesis. 3. Run experiment and collect data. 4. Analyze data. 5. Compare analyzed data to hypothesis to see whether the data supports or does not support (those are the only two options) the hypothesis. And of course, you'd likely write up your results. I have not studied Bayesian methods, so the term "priors" is not familiar enough for me to comment on your Argument 1. How does your #1 compare with my 1-5?

Comment: What exactly do you think is "the usual approach"? There are several distinct approaches to hypotheses, evidence and probability and I suspect that you have not chosen among them.

Comment: The necessity of forming a hypothesis before the data are in hand goes ONLY with the Neyman–Pearsonian 'hypothesis test' approach. It is usually not the approach that you should be using.

Comment: @MichaelLew Hi could you describe what the multiple approaches are outside the NP approach?

Comment: The main non-NP approaches are neo-Fisherian significance testing and Bayesian approaches. They are both, imo (and others', including Sander Greenland: https://statmodeling.stat.columbia.edu/2021/09/27/when-should-clinicians-act-on-non-statistically-significant-results-from-clinical-trials/) more useful than decision-theoretic Neyman–Pearsonian hypothesis tests. I've written of the difference between neo-Fisherian p-values and hypothesis tests, and an explanation of the essential difference between statistical and scientific inference: https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/164_2019_286